# Static IP "Some other host already uses address "

Tags: centos, networking, network-interface

Hello I'm trying to set up a static ip on a minimal install vm with the IP of the vm is `170.20.x.100` but when I configure the`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` file to have an IPADDR of 172.20.x.100 and I restart the network with systemctl I get an error saying "***Error, some other host already uses address*** `172.20.x.100` and when I change the ip to any other value the ip does resolve and it validates I have checked all of the other hosts on my network and none has that ip on any interface.

Although I did find a file on the main host called `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-br1` and it does have the ip of 172.20.x.100 in the IPADDR field, but when I do ifconfig on the interface it does not show that ip instead it shows 172.20.x.1 which is the correct address, I'm using my main hosts as the gateway of my network. This is also a cloned VM and I have been encountering several issues before. I couldn't ping my gateway before because the MAC address of the virtual machine and the MAC of *ifcfg-eth0* file
were different but I changed it to the MAC Virt-Manager gave me and it worked. Now the only issue is getting my vm to obtain 172.20.x.100 as the ip address. Are you familiar with this issue?

**UPDATE**
It seems like the issue is still the MAC address.

When I issue

```
arping -c 2 -w 3 -D -I eth0 172.20.x.100 The reply is 
Unicast reply from 172.20.x.100 from 0.0.0.0 eth0
Unicast reply from 172.20.x.100 [ 52:54:00:D0:5D:3A ]
```

but when I go ifconfig eth0 on the vm the MAC is

```
52:54:00:4b:c2:30
```

[image]

Static configuration of vm `/etc/sysconfig/network-script/ifcfg-eth0`

```
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPADDR=172.20.x.100
GATEWAY=172.20.x.1
DNS1=172.20.x.1
DNS2=8.8.8.8
HWADDR=52:54:00:4b:c2:30
PEERDNS=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
IPV6INIT=no
```

Ifconfig on main host:

```
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.40.84.195  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.40.84.255
        inet6 fe80::d4de:7ab0:3cf4:e2ca  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ec:b1:d7:38:c7:07  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 162478  bytes 70643148 (67.3 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 37498  bytes 6406695 (6.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xef100000-ef120000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 189  bytes 21522 (21.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 189  bytes 21522 (21.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.51.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.51.255
        ether 52:54:00:7b:f7:52  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 34  bytes 1948 (1.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6  bytes 2374 (2.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.20.x.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.20.x.255
        ether 52:54:00:d0:5d:3a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 664  bytes 91395 (89.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 397  bytes 493153 (481.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Content of br1:

```
DEVICE="br1"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Bridge"
BOOTPROTO="none"
IPADDR="172.20.x.100"
GATEWAY="172.20.x.1"
STP="on"
DELAY="0.0"
```

Error Message of VM:
[image]

Comment: You've shown the results of `ifconfig`, but what about `ip addr`? I've noticed that `ifconfig` doesn't always list all IPs, especially when an interface has multiple. `br1` on you main host certainly seems to clash with `eth0` on your VM (given the `IPADDR=` lines are the same).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello the br1 interface it's your bridged interface, it's diferent from virbr0 and virbr1, the br1 interface is the interface which will send packets from you hypervisor. All vms will use this interface to communicate with the the outside world.

you just change the value of one of them, the eth0 or br0.

```
br1 = 170.20.x.100

eth0 = 170.20.x.10
```

for example ^^.